# Save and retrieve multiple value given through jsp from database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have one jsp page where  I am selecting value using multiple option and sending to servlet and trying to store into database i Have selected two values through multiple option an error is coming like this .Net
               Core Java,
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 , here is my jsp code

```
                    <tr>
  <td><label>Skills </label>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><select name="skills" size="5" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
    <option value="Android">Android</option>
    <option value=".Net">.Net</option>
    <option value="Core Java">Core Java</option>
    <option value="Advance Java">Advance Java</option>
    <option value="Database">Database</option>
    <option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
    <option value="Html/CSS">Html/CSS</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="TESTING">TESTING</option>
    <option value="Networking">Networking</option>

  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and after that i am retrieving value in servlet like this..

```
 String[] skills   =request.getParameterValues("skills");
    for(p=0;p<skills.length;p++)
    {

    System.out.println(skills[p]);
    }
```

now storing into database like this....

```
  int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into empinfo(skills) values (+skills[p] + "')");
    if (i > 0) {

  }
```

please  help me anyone here how to store and retrieve using jsp and servlet

here is my table structure.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empinfo` (
     `eid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `dob` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bloodgroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
 `qualification` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailid` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contactnum` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `skills` varchar(1250) NOT NULL,
`temporaryadd` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL,
`permanentadd` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL,
`access_type` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`eid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: at which line you are getting the exception ? the first part or the second where you are trying to save it to database ? or post the stacktraces

Comment: sir i i am able to see the value on console using System.. that command so i have already printed .net and core java  it is coming on console and after that i have already posted that message "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 " so it must be in skills[i] when i am storing it may be going out of array index how to resolve this....

Comment: Does `System.out.println(skills[p]);` prints the desired values ?

Comment: yes  it is printing desired values..

Answer (score 1):

```
  String[] skills   =request.getParameterValues("skills");
  String value="";
            for(p=0;p<skills.length;p++)
            {
                value += skills[p]+",";
            }
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into empinfo(skills) values (+value+ "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the prepared statement instead .

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE(stringArray) VALUES    (?)");    
Array a = conn.createArrayOf("skills", arr);
pstmt.setArray(1, arr);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sir that i have given here only one field , i have so many field and values are same time all are normal value... only this one i have in array form so i have to go in sequence so plz tel me in that way..

Comment: Can you post your table structure ?

Comment: sir this link is related to my problem only but he is able to stored into database i want to save first so just check it and tell me if you can help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233466/multiple-checkbox-options-stored-into-a-single-field-in-a-database